# Updated util.scanner repeating method

Tags: java, string, methods, return, java.util.scanner

I have fixed the errors in my original code and formatted it correctly.  However, the code is now repeating String next() before it proceeds to the last method.  I thought I understood why, but when I tried to fix it, the program failed again.  Thank you for your time!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LearnScanner {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        first();
        next();
        third();
    }
    public static void first() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to Vacation Planner!!");
        System.out.print("What is your name?");
        String name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Nice to meet you " + name + ", where are you travelling to?");
        String destination = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Great! "+destination +" sounds like a great trip");
     }
    public static String next() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many days are you going to spend travelling?");
        String days = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("How much money in USD are you planning to spend on your trip?");
        String budget = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("What is the three letter currency symbol for your travel destination?");
        String currency = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("How many " + currency + " are there in 1 USD?");
        String currencyConversion = input.nextLine();
        return days;
    }
    public static void third() {
        int days = Integer.valueOf(next());
        int hours = days * 24;
        int minutes = hours * 60;
        System.out.println("If your are travelling for " + days + " days that is the same as " + hours + " hours or " + minutes + " minutes");
    }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, the method next() gets called once from the main method, and then gets called again in third at

```
int days = Integer.valueOf(next());
```

Maybe you should create an instance variable called days and store the value of next() in it. Then use the value of the variable in the third() method. i.e.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LearnScanner {
    private static int days = 0;

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        first();
        days = Integer.parseInt(next());
        third();
    }
    public static void first() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to Vacation Planner!!");
        System.out.print("What is your name?");
        String name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Nice to meet you " + name + ", where are you travelling to?");
        String destination = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Great! "+destination +" sounds like a great trip");
     }
    public static String next() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many days are you going to spend travelling?");
        String days = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("How much money in USD are you planning to spend on your trip?");
        String budget = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("What is the three letter currency symbol for your travel destination?");
        String currency = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("How many " + currency + " are there in 1 USD?");
        String currencyConversion = input.nextLine();
        return days;
    }
    public static void third() {
        int tempDays = Integer.valueOf(days);
        int hours = days * 24;
        int minutes = hours * 60;
        System.out.println("If your are travelling for " + tempDays + " days that is the same as " + hours + " hours or " + minutes + " minutes");
    }
```

Comment: This is the correct answer

Comment: After applying this change I get the following error:          java: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to int

Comment: I get that.. You should convert the String to Integer. I'll refactor the code now

Comment: @ErikBrabo I have added the conversion

Comment: Thank you for the update, however the error is: java: variable days might not have been initialized

Comment: Hey @ErikBrabo, the issue here is that there is already a local variable 'days' in third() which conflicts with the instance variable we have. The code has been refactored.